# SQL Ordering by field value

Tags: mysql, sql

I Have following table.

[image]

Simply i want to make order by `meta_key` where value is `LoginTS`. its a bit distracting.

`ORDER BY meta_value( where meta_key is LoginTS )  DESC` .

Im sorry if its not clear enough..

> Expected Result :
>   [image]

Comment: Can you add the expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   mytable 
WHERE `meta_key`= 'LoginTS' 
ORDER  BY `meta_value` DESC
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c7a5/5)**

If you want to get back all the Table but to ORDER BY specific column try this:

```
SELECT
 *
FROM
  myTable
  ORDER BY CASE WHEN `meta_key`='LoginTS' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO 2**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c7a5/7)

Comment: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0006 sec) , don't know why tho

Comment: it's 'LoginTS', but not 'LoginTs'. the 's' should not be in lower case.

Comment: @Saeid Khaleghi try again i fixed the query

Comment: tyvm this one works too, id prefer to use this one. thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

WHERE should be placed before ORDER BY, try this:

```
WHERE meta_key = 'LoginTS' ORDER BY meta_value DESC
```

Comment: It was ASC when I copied it from the question... I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to order by asc, you could try something like this

```
order by case when meta_key='LoginTS' then 0 else 1 end
```

Comment: @SaeidKhaleghi How would this gives you the expected result. You have only two records where `meta_key='LoginTS'` but this will result all the records

Comment: @Prdp  i just used this and im getting exact result as i wanted.

Comment: @SaeidKhaleghi - Then your expected result in question is wrong. It is misleading

Comment: @OneManCrew chill , ive got some results with this one as well but the one you pointed at is more like it, clear.